# Centrar span con imagen dentro de una columna td

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, datatables

Como puedo centrar un `<span class="glyphicon"></span>` dentro de un `<td>` de una tabla?. Es un poco engorroso ponerlos en tema...estoy usando Laravel 5.2 y DataTable de jquery. Es una columna que me llegan valores 1 o 0 y yo, en mi javascript reemplazo por un gliphicon si es valor 1 o si es valor 0 para obtener la imagen que les adjunto. El tema es que me gustaria que esté centrada (columna Activo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Estas usando bootstrap?

Comment: @rnd, si, estoy usando bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando crees la tabla usa la opción `columns` para poder añadir una clase a todos los `td` de una columna concreta con `className`. Datatables viene con clases para alinear celdas, si estas usando sus estilos puedes usar la clase `dt-center` o utilizar la de bootstrap: `text-center`:

```
var table = $('#lotes-establecimiento').DataTable({
  "columns": [{
    "data": "lote"
  }, {
    "data": "tipo"    
  }, {
    "data": "activo"
    "className": "text-center"
  },{
    "data":"descripcion"
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Como un `span` es un elemento `inline`, puedes usar `text-align: center` para centrar el elemento dentro de la columna.

Ejemplo:

```css
td{
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tal y como te ha comentado @rnd, usando el selector directamente del elemento se cambiará para todos los elementos de ese tipo que tengas en tu página. Yo simplemente lo puse a modo de ejemplo rápido para que vieras que se podía centrar mediante la propiedad `text-align: center`. En caso de que la tabla fuera estática podrías usar una clase.

Como en tu caso, la tabla se crea dinámicamente, puedes hacer referencia a la columna 3 de cada una de las filas mediante el selector `nth-child(3)` usando `tr > td:nth-child(3)`. Esto indica que coja el elemento `td` con la posición 3 que sea hijo de un `tr`.

Ejemplo:

```css
td{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

tr > td:nth-child(3){
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
    <td><span>Esto es una prueba</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: el inconveniente es que me lo centra para TODAS las columnas y no es la idea...solo quiero centrar esa columna.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres eso pasa por que con este selector (`td`) pisas los estilos de todos los elementos `<td>`, si en cambio usas una clase y la agregas a tu `<td>` funcionaria como quieres. De todos modos, fijate en mi respuesta pues no necesitas agregar css adicional ya que bootstrap incuye una clase para hacer esto mismo.

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Ya esta editada la respuesta.

Comment: Error404, gracias!. Funciona bien. Solo que me quedo con la respuesta de @blonfu dado que es mas específica en cuanto al uso de DataTables. Gracias nuevamente por la colaboracion!

Comment: @EmilianoTorres De nada :) Sí, tiene más sentido para este caso en cuanto a contexto y por eso le di +1. Lo bueno de mi ejemplo es que lo puedes usar para cualquier tabla y no solo para las DataTables. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estas usando Bootstrap, no necesitas agregar CSS adicional.

Agrega la clase [`.text-center`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) al contenedor, como en la segunda fila de este ejemplo.

Salu2

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: es que no tengo un td definido...me lo dá el DataTable. Yo en mi html solo tengo el header...el resto viene dinamico por el DataTable

Comment: @EmilianoTorres ah. se me escapo que usabas dataTable. Fijate la respuesta de blonfu. Si estas usando otro plugin de tablas que el mencionado en esa repuesta avisame. Salu2